# UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 JDK compiler is 1.7, JRE is java7

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, xquery, basex

I want to use BaseX in eclipse.
I installed and set up BaseX reffering to [this](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Integrating_Eclipse) site, as standalone.
but 2 errors occurred when I execute query.

1st error is "UnsupportedClassVersionError."

I know this error occurred because of JDK version by past questions.
But I confirmed  that I set JDK compiler as 1.7 and installed JRE as java7.
So, I have no idea at all.

And 2nd error is "Could not find the main class: org.basex.BaseX."
I write "org.basex.BaseX" in Main class in Edit interpreter following to above site, but not choose..

My eclipse version is indigo.

error message is as below

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/basex/BaseX : Unsupported      major.minor version 51.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: org.basex.BaseX.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main"
```

Comment: What JRE shows when you go to the debug dialog, click on your application, and click on the JRE tab?

Comment: What version of Java is running Eclipse itself? Select `Help` > `About Eclipse`, click `Installation Details`, select the `Configuration` tab, then look for the `java.version` system property.

Comment: actually, java.version is 1.6 when I confirm it from Help > About Eclipse, click Installation Details, select the Configuration tab! I thought I can change java version from Preference-> java. how to fix this problem?

Comment: BTW: your Eclipse version appears to be older than the Java version you're trying to use. Please consider upgrading to get more than 5 years worth of bug fixes and new features.

Answer (score 0):

When using Eclipse for Java development you could theoretically use three different JREs in combination:

- One for running Eclipse it self, this is limited only by Eclipse's own requirements (1.8 as of Neon)
- One for the libraries to compile against. This is what you see in the Build Path properties of your project. This decides what library classes and function can be referenced by your program (checked at compile time).
- One to launch your programs (Run / Debug).

It's the latter that is relevant here. You'll find it all described starting from ["Working with JREs"](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-JREs.htm?cp=1_3_5), then drill down into "Choosing a JRE for launching a project".

Of course, suitable defaults can reduce the effort to configure similar things in several locations, see, e.g., "Choosing a default JRE" on the above help page.